# Swing and Android Apps with shared code base and resources

Tags: java, android, swing, android-resources

In my company we would like to develop a swing and a android application. Both should basically have the same functions. So we thought to create a normal java project with the core code, a java project for XML communication with the endpoint (both apps use the same endpoint) and a java project for shared resources like bundles, images and so on.

Now the drawback: After having a first look at android we noticed that android handles resources very much different from any other system. Everything has to be in XML files and logos/images have to be in different folders with different resolutions. From my understanding this would mean to discard the idea of a shared resource project and to maintain the resources two times: one time for swing in the form of bundles and the like and another time for android.

Our architecture is layer based: the business logic layer defines functions that are the core functionalities of the app. The presentation layer should grab the functions and build the layout dynamically based on the role of the logged in user. Here too, I'm not sure how to archive this with android.

Questions:

- Is it possible to have the applications use the same resources?
- Do someone know another way how to handle this? (I'm a noob with android)

All comments, ideas and alternatives are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have string resources in xml for android, so it will parse them by itself, so all you need in your desktop app is to write parser to grab this resources and use them. I believe it's better then duplicating. In case if you have too much resources you can put them in few xml files, that will be the same: android will grab them automatically but you will just change file name.

Comment: i do think the same - instead of starting by 'plain java' you better start off with android - once you know how ressources are manages there it's very easy to make an adapter for 'plain java' .... (excuse my remark-quotes, i don't else to express ...

Comment: No problem, I got u. Yes 'case java is more general that Android y'd better start from android in this case but for all the general logic u'd better start from Java. I have kind of experience with that.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, even though it answers my questions just partly. Nevertheless it put me in the right direction so thank you.